# Functions problem displaying the output and intput

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that will get 2 integers. The program will then display the
following:
a. The sum of all integers that are both divisible by 4 and 6 between the two numbers inputted.
b. The average of all integers both divisible by 3 and 7 between the two numbers inputted.

I tried doing the code down below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Sum46(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i % 6 == 0) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int Sum37(int j, int k)
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = j; i <= k; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {

            sum1 = sum1 + i;
        }
    }
    return sum1;
}

int Count(int f, int g)
{
    int inputCount = 0;
    for (int i = f; i < g; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) {
            inputCount++;
        }
    }
    return inputCount;
}

int Ave(int t, int u)
{
    int total = 0;
    total = t / u;
    return total;
}

void display(int o, int l)
{
    cout << "The sum of all integers that are both divisible by 4 and 6 between two numbers is " << o << endl;
    cout << "The sum of all integers that are both divisible by 3 and 7 between two numbers is " << l << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    int probA, probB, comp, bilang;
    cout << "Input first number : ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Input second number : ";
    cin >> num2;

    probA = Sum46(num1, num2);
    comp = Sum37(num1, num2);
    bilang = Count(num1, num2);
    probB = Ave(comp, bilang);
    display(probA, probB);

    return 0;
}
```

My expected result should be

Input first number : 4
Input second number : 12

The sum of all integers that are both divisible by 4 and 6 between two numbers is 12 
The sum of all integers that are both divisible by 3 and 7 between two numbers is 0
"since 12 is the only number that is both divisible by 4 and 6 and no number is divisible by 3 and 7 on the inputted numbers."

But the actual results are 
Input first number : 4
Input second number : 12
"That is the only result and I was not able to produce any output of the functions"

Comment: If `Count()` returns `0` you get a divide by zero exception.

Comment: When debugging in Visual Studio it showed me that @JohnnyMopp was correct. in the ave() function both parameters are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the case where u is 0.

Change this:

```
int Ave(int t, int u)
{
    int total = 0;
    total = t / u;
    return total;
}
```

To this:

```
int Ave(int t, int u)
{
    if( u == 0 )
        return -1;
    return t/u;
}
```

Comment: it returns -1 value

Comment: -1 is the default error code of C++ libs. You can return what you want. Maybe 0 is here better. But you definetly have to catch the division through 0. 

You could throw a division through 0 exception for example. But this is the line where your code breaks.

Comment: I see thanks for the info. By the way, how can I return Ave function on my Display function?

Comment: You may want to not make display a function. Instead just display your results directly in main. Either that or pass the additional parameters.